# Sharing I/O across home and work computer

Tags: networking, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, kvm-switch

I have a dual monitor setup, with various USB (type A) plugins that need a total of 3 USB type A ports. One of the monitors is DisplayPort/HDMI and the other is just HDMI.

What I am looking to do is have some way where I easily switch I/O between my work laptop and my home computer, because right now I am manually unplugging all of the cables and it is getting rather tedious.

Some options I have looked into:

1. KVM switches, but it was starting to look complicated because most KVM switches don't support all of this I/O, so I would need some weird scheme of multiple usb-c hubs and cables.
2. Both my work-pc and my home pc have a USB-C port, is there some way I could just plug in a dual sided usb-c to both and switch that way? I am thinking this would need some extra software, but essentially this is what I'd end up doing with the KVM switch/hub solution.
3. I've tried chrome remote desktop, but that is much to slow for what I am doing, maybe there's something that offers much quicker speeds?

I am looking for advice/any other solution to this, I might be over complicating it because I am having a hard time finding solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A "Dual-Monitor KVM switch" is the way to go. You will need one USB-Hub in addition to this KVM switch. Connect both computers with one USB cable each to the switch, and apply the USB-Hub at the "Mouse/Keyboard" side of the KVM switch.

Most of these switches only support USB 2.0, and depending on the actual USB 2.0 speed ("Full Speed" = 1MB/s or "Hi-Speed" = 40 MB/s), some USB devices like Webcams won't work. I have this issue, and I simply use two Webcams, directly attached to the respective computers.